# How to capture error reason of "ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code." from Metamask in the front-end

Tags: solidity, transactions, metamask, frontend

Let's say we have a smart contract `test` with a function `foo()` and a modifier so that only the contract owner can call this function.

Now we have a front-end with a user that is not the contract owner and is calling this function: the user will see the following alert in Metamask before confirming the transaction:

> ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

My question: is there a way to capture the error reason from the front-end to show the user why the transaction will fail? it looks like Metamask is "*pre-launching*" the transaction and detecting that some condition will fail (either require, out of gas, etc).

The closest thing I've been able to do from the front-end is to catch the error **after** the transaction has failed:

```
    await test.methods
        .foo()
        .send({ from: wallet.account })
        .on('error', (err: any) => {
            console.log('Error description: ', err);
            return;
        });
```

And even this way, the error description is just showing false in the `status` field. The goal would be to show the user why the transaction will fail **before** actually launching such a transaction.